Confusion regarding PCA, FA, and PCR?
I learned here: Is PCA followed by a rotation (such as varimax) still PCA?
About the relationship between PCA and FA and how they each provide a perspective for looking at the same thing. However, at work, I ran into some legacy code which does something strange, at least within the framework described in the above post (will summarise).
In the post, author says that SVD gives us
$X=USV^⊤$
which we can then break down into an orthonormal basis and component scores (PCA view) or latent unit-variance variables and their loadings (FA view), by grouping the $S$ matrix wither with $U$ ($US$ = component scores in PCA and $V$ has the basis) or with $V$ ($VS$ is the loadings matrix and $U$ has factors).
This makes a lot of sense, but the code I saw has someone computing PCA, extracting the loadings as described above (eigenvectors scaled by sqrt(eigenvalues)), then regresses the original matrix on those loadings to find the factors, the result is, of course, different. What is the meaning of this difference? what are the advantages to each?

If PCR means Principal Components Regression, that term is used in the literature I know for a different thing from what you discuss here, although I cannot exclude the possibility that it is also used for this kind of approach somewhere. (It's a good idea to explain all abbreviations you use as there is loads of literature and abbreviations are not necessarily standardised.)

It's hard to comment on "the code I saw" if we don't see it, and we also don't know what was meant to be achieved by that code (although one can guess of course).

regresses the original matrix on those loadings This is unclear and strange. The original matrix seems to be the data, n x p. But loadings are p x m. (m is the number of factors). How can loadings be regressors then? Loadings are regression coefficients.
